# How do I POST raw JSON data without using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an API endpoint that I want to call. It seems an easy task but to my surprise, it isn't. Here's why:

- I can't use AJAX because the response of this API is a file to download. So I probably need to create a hidden iframe and send regular POST request from there.
- I need to POST data as a raw JSON string, not in form data. The API does not accept key value pairs. So I can't just create an HTML form and submit it.
- This is not my API. I can't change it.

Now I'm stuck. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: _"because the response of this API is a file to download"_, AJAX requests can retrieve files, you just have to do an extra step for it to have the file save to a user's local system

Comment: What is a "raw JSON string"? So the API "does not accept key value pairs [JSON]" and you want to send JSON via a HTML form? Huh?

Comment: Could you provide a sample data that the API will accept to understand better?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Do you mean File API? I'm looking into it but the browser support isn't very good.

Comment: No, when you get a file through an ajax request you can transform it into an object url / data uri and set it as a href on an anchor that has its [`download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) attribute set to true. Kosch's answer below has an example of that

Comment: @Vohuman Vijai I mean the API does not accept form-data or x-www-form-urlencoded. The request payload must be a raw string which is in JSON format.

Comment: 1. You want to give some values using POST method without using "key value pairs". 2. To use POST you need to use AJAX or a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with ajax or raw XMLHttpRequest()

A few things already mentioned in the commments to your question that explain what's going on here.

First you need a request object.  Posting is no problemo, you'll pass the JSON payload you've gotta send on that last line there.  After the POST is successful you'll need to take the binary returned and make an Blob for the correct file type, an objecctUrl and finally a hidden link that you'll click for the user.  Please note the download attribute.  This lets modern browsers know it's a download link which let's the download roll.

I've probably got some of this code from stackoverflow...

```
  const xlsx = {};
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', '/data/some.ashx');
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  xhr.onload = function loadXLXS() {
    let objectUrl;
    if (this.status === 200) {
       blob = this.response
       csvURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       tempLink = document.createElement('a');
       tempLink.href = csvURL;
       tempLink.setAttribute('download', workBookName);
       tempLink.click();
    }
  };
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(xlsx));
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of what you are doing. Especially the object url creation and anchor use as OP and others may not know about them. Also `xhr.responseType = 'blob'` by setting that to `blob`,  `xhr.response` should already be a blob object, no need to do `blob = new Blob()`

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot!